# MySQL cluster - Does distribution-aware query and stored procedure are conflict idea?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cluster-computing

Both stored procedure and distribution-aware query are significant for MySQL Cluster performance.

- Stored procedure is used to reduce number of query transmission from client software to MySQL server. We use one time procedure call to run many queries.
- Distribution-aware query is used to reduce unnecessary table scan on unnecessary node.

As I known, stored procedure works on each node.
I'm afraid that when I use stored procedure implies that I can't utilize distribution-aware query.  When I use distribution-aware query implies that I can't utilize stored procedure.

Is that true?

Any Idea to utilize both stored procedure and distribution-aware query for better performance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Stored procedures and distribution aware queries are independent of each other. If a query is distriution aware it will also be distribution aware running inside the stored procedure. Queries are distribution aware if they query the primary key. If there are multiple queries in a single transaction the first query of that transaction will decide which data node this transaction will use. All queries inside the transaction will go to the same partition.

However, I am not sure why you think that stored procedures will give you a great performance win.

Bernd